# Prevent ExtJS Tree Node anchor from firing, but no hash

Tags: extjs, onclick, treenode

I need to prevent tree node anchor from navigating current page, but the anchors have to keep showing its link (no hash).

I tried to put `return false` when it sets up the `listener`:

```
...
listeners : {
    click : function (node) {
        /* some processes */

        return false;
    }
}
...
```

Seems it is useless, the anchors are still firing its href.

I can't do onClick injection for all nodes, because the nodes are loaded on demand.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't do onClick injection for all
>   nodes, because the nodes are loaded on
>   demand.

Not necessarily, have you thought about doing this with a different approach, i.e.:

```
YOURTREEPANELCOMPONENT.on('click',function(currentnode, clickevent){
   // prevent href from being called and the page from loading
   clickevent.stopEvent();
   // what else to do when the node is clicked
});
```

Comment: You can do it either way as long as the event param is included and stopEvent (or preventDefault) is called.